# Clickable HTML Table in email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to create a clickable HTML table that doesn't make the text appear hyperlinked -- and that makes the entire table linked. After spending hours sifting through the previous posts on this topic, I thought I had figured the code out and got it to work in an HTML editor.

However, when I send myself test email samples, the code is not working. In Outlook, the table appears clickable but is not linked. In Gmail, it doesn't appear clickable and is not linked.

A very helpful commenter let me know that I can't have an `<a>` tag outside the table, but if I move the `<a>` tag to inside the `<td>` then it will only link the text, not the whole table.

Is there a workaround for this?

Here is my code:

```
<a href="http://google.com" style="text-decoration:none">
  <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="width:200px;">
     <tbody>
         <tr id="clickable" style="cursor:pointer">    
            <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>TEXT</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>TEXT</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>TEXT</strong></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="clickable" style="cursor:pointer">
            <td style="text-align: center;">
               <strong><span style="color:#0c85c8;">TEXT</span>-<span style="color:#e7413D;">TEXT</span></strong>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <strong><span style="color:#0c85c8;">TEXT</span>-<span style="color:#e7413D;">TEXT</span></strong>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <strong><span style="color:#0c85c8;">TEXT</span>-<span style="color:#e7413D;">TEXT</span></strong>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</a>
```

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: You can't do <a> around a table. You need to do <a> inside each td

Comment: I'm trying to make the whole table linked though. Won't putting it in the td tags make only the text linked?

Comment: @HeshamAbuSaif As of HTML5, you can now wrap many elements, including `<table>`, in an anchor tag.

Comment: @Rob to be fair, this is email we're dealing with here.

Comment: @Frish Yes, I must have missed that, and I don't recall if this works in email.

Comment: @digitalstaffer I could not reproduce your problem. When I sent an email containing the above HTML, it yielded a table that was clickable. How are you sending the email? Perhaps your mailer is stripping out such links. In Gmail there's an option to 'Show original' by which you can view the original message before HTML rendering; from that you can see if the message is being received with links. If there are no hrefs then likely your mailer is removing them.

Comment: @jla I am using a mass-mailing system called Blue State Digital (BSD), and every email we send is coded (a much different process than a regular email client like Gmail). The system does include a "preview" option and the table is clickable in the preview. However it is not working when tests are sent, for some reason.

Comment: @digitalstaffer if you check `Original message` in the _received_ message in Gmail (or Outlook, etc) you can see if the hrefs are present. If not then they are being removed before the email client has even received them.

Comment: @jla I see what you're saying now, thank you! I viewed the original, and interestingly, the table (or the text within it) are not appearing *at all* in the original. There is a version of the code in the original HTML, but it has been chopped up and modified by gmail so I can't interpret what it's trying to tell me. The href and link appear in a different form in that HTML sample, however.

Comment: @digitalstaffer interesting, in that case it seems that your mailer may be the culprit. The only suggestion I can give is to gradually build up your email, i.e. first a table, then add links, etc, testing each stage to find out at what point it's going wrong. Once you find that point you can try a workaround

Comment: @digitalstaffer   I am facing the same problem but in outlook. Outlook remove the <a> surrounding the table. Can you suggest something to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a style `color: inherit;`in your `<a>` tag. It should looks like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit">
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit">
      <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="width:200px;">
         <tbody>
             <tr id="clickable" style="cursor:pointer">
                <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>TEXT</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>TEXT</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>TEXT</strong></td>
             </tr>
             <tr id="clickable" style="cursor:pointer">
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                   <strong><span style="color:#0c85c8;">TEXT</span>-<span style="color:#e7413D;">TEXT</span></strong>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <strong><span style="color:#0c85c8;">TEXT</span>-<span style="color:#e7413D;">TEXT</span></strong>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <strong><span style="color:#0c85c8;">TEXT</span>-<span style="color:#e7413D;">TEXT</span></strong>
                </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this was meant to solve the clickable problem or if it was just a separate problem with my code. However, I tested it with this code and have the same problem.

Comment: Mail has a lot of limitations though. It cannot interpret all the styles in your code. Aside from that, email clients have different responses to your code, that's why you have to make your code as simple as possible.